# Google Analytics V4 Hello Analytics + Check Request Pemission Status Before Running BatchGet()

Tags: php, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

1. I'm running some GA Requests as per [Reporting API v4 (PHP)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/samples)
2. I'm looping through multiple View IDs, some of which don't have the correct permissions. (I'm aware what permissions are required, however, sometimes I don't have the necessary access for one reason or another). When this happens, I get a 403 request error: `"User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile."` ... which I understand
3. While I'm looping through IDs, if one view ID returns such an error, it breaks my loop.
4. I would like to check the request status before executing `$analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );` so that it doesn't break my loop. (i.e. don't run it if it returns an error).
5. My Question: What method can I call to check the request status before running `batchGet()`?

My Code

```
foreach($view_ids as $view_id){
    // Create the DateRange object.
    $dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
    $dateRange->setStartDate("2015-06-15");
    $dateRange->setEndDate("2015-06-30");

    // Create the Metrics object.
    $sessions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
    $sessions->setExpression("ga:sessions");
    $sessions->setAlias("sessions");

    //Create the Dimensions object.
    $browser = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Dimension();
    $browser->setName("ga:browser");

    // Create the ReportRequest object.
    $request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
    $request->setViewId($view_id);
    $request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
    $request->setDimensions(array($browser));
    $request->setMetrics(array($sessions));

    $body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
    $body->setReportRequests( array( $request) );

    // THIS IS WHERE I'M GETTING STUCK, DON'T KNOW WHICH METHOD TO CALL
    //$request_status_code = $analyticsreporting->reports->[whichMethod]???
    if($request_status_code == 200){
        return $analyticsreporting->reports->batchGet( $body );
    }
}
```

Comment: Why dont you get a list of the views the user has access to before sending requests against views they dont have access to.

Comment: @DalmTo Could you point me to the right direction to that method? I've been going off of the 'Hello Analytics' model (which seems to address pulling 'data' as opposed to 'view-based permissions.'

Answer (score 0):

Let the user pick which view they want to access then run your code against that view.  This code will show you how to list the views a user has access to.

## [accountsummeries.list](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accountSummaries/list)

```
/**
 * Note: This code assumes you have an authorized Analytics service object.
 * See the Account Summaries Developer Guide for details.
 */

/**
 * Example #1:
 * Requests a list of all account summaries for the authorized user.
 */
try {
  $accounts = $analytics->management_accountSummaries
      ->listManagementAccountSummaries();
} catch (apiServiceException $e) {
  print 'There was an Analytics API service error '
        . $e->getCode() . ':' . $e->getMessage();

} catch (apiException $e) {
  print 'There was a general API error '
      . $e->getCode() . ':' . $e->getMessage();
}

/**
 * Example #2:
 * The results of the list method are stored in the accounts object.
 * The following code shows how to iterate through them.
 */
foreach ($accounts->getItems() as $account) {
  $html = <<<HTML
<pre>
Account id   = {$account->getId()}
Account kind = {$account->getKind()}
Account name = {$account->getName()}
HTML;

  // Iterate through each Property.
  foreach ($account->getWebProperties() as $property) {
    $html .= <<<HTML
Property id          = {$property->getId()}
Property kind        = {$property->getKind()}
Property name        = {$property->getName()}
Internal property id = {$property->getInternalWebPropertyId()}
Property level       = {$property->getLevel()}
Property URL         = {$property->getWebsiteUrl()}
HTML;

    // Iterate through each view (profile).
    foreach ($property->getProfiles() as $profile) {
      $html .= <<<HTML
Profile id   = {$profile->getId()}
Profile kind = {$profile->getKind()}
Profile name = {$profile->getName()}
Profile type = {$profile->getType()}
HTML;
    }
  }
  $html .= '</pre>';
  print $html;
}
```